# Adding a class to every other item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a list of products. I would like every other element to get a class
`:before`, or `:after`, or just `.My-clas`

```
<div class="product-single"></div>    
<div class="product-single"></div> <!-- here I need add class -->    
<div class="product-single"></div>    
<div class="product-single"></div> <!-- here I need add class -->
```

The products will be added by the administrator, so I need to know how to add every other element because I don't know how many administrator will add them there ...

Comment: why not just use nth-child selector? Do you need the class for anything other than styling?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector, https://api.jquery.com/addClass. However you should note that you don't need JS for this, as it can be done in CSS alone using the  `:nth-child` selector

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child, btw didn't downvote, it's pretty normal not to know things.

Comment: @TahaPaksu The downvote is most likely for doing no research, and showing no effort. Not for not knowing something.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes you are absolutely right, but I had times when I couldn't even figure out what to search until I figured out to look at the source code of whose achieved what I've wanted :)

Comment: Agreed, however if you google the title of this question it links you straight to an SO question with the relevant solution

Comment: there will be one more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery or JavaScript here; you can target those elements by combining the `nth-child` selector with the `after` psuedo-element:

```css
.product-single {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

.product-single:nth-child(even):after {
  content: ':after';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-single"></div>    
<div class="product-single"></div> <!-- here I need add class -->    
<div class="product-single"></div>    
<div class="product-single"></div> <!-- here I need add class -->
```

Comment: No problem, @Simon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.product-single:nth-child(even)').addClass('something');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `odd` / `even` selector with `div`.

```js
$('div:odd').addClass('yourClass');
```

```css
.yourClass {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-single">1</div>
<div class="product-single">2</div>
<!-- here I need add class -->
<div class="product-single">3</div>
<div class="product-single">4</div>
<!-- here I need add class -->
```